# Llamar a un metodo sin devolver un return

Tags: java, metodología

Tengo un codigo donde mide tu peso , sin embargo yo quiero que el metodo no me retone nada si no que por medio de toString yo lo pueda imprimir todo dentro de un record.

este es el codigo

```
public record Dominio() implements Comparable<Dominio> {

public static String Nombre;
    public static String Sexo;
    public static Double Peso;
    public static Double Altura;
    public static String EstadoNutricional;

public Dominio(String nombre,String sexo,Double peso,Double altura){
        Nombre = nombre;
        Sexo = sexo;
        Peso = peso;
        Altura = altura;
        Double CalculoPeso =  Peso/Altura;
        if(CalculoPeso < 18.0){
            EstadoNutricional = "Bajo peso";
        }
        if(CalculoPeso < 24.9){
            EstadoNutricional = "Normal";
        }
        if(CalculoPeso < 26.9){
            EstadoNutricional = "Sobrepeso";
        }
        if(CalculoPeso < 29.9){
            EstadoNutricional = "Obesidad ";
        }
        if(CalculoPeso < 34.9){
            EstadoNutricional = "ObesidadI";
        }
        if(CalculoPeso < 39.9){
            EstadoNutricional = "ObesidadII";
        }
        if(CalculoPeso > 40.0){
            EstadoNutricional = "ObesidadIII";
        }
}
```

Ahora ya que tengo mis variables ya almacenadas quiero que por medio de un toString funcione este codigo.

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        
        return "La persona :"+Nombre+"con sexo:"+Sexo+"Con peso y estatura"+Peso+"Kg"+Altura+"m2"+"Tiene"+EstadoNutricional+"------------------------";
    }
```

sin embargo me sale este error el `public Dominio (String nombre,String sexo,Double peso,Double altura)`
 `A non-canonical constructor must start with an explicit invocation to constructor`
gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Por qué los atributos son estáticos? Así no los podrá acceder el método no-estático `toString()`.

Comment: si lo quito el static me dice error.

Answer (score 0):

el parametro void te hace justo lo que buscas.

```
public void setPeso(Double Peso){ 
   this.Peso=Peso 
}
```

Listo asi tienes una función que pasandole por parametro el valor que quieres asignarle a una variable se le asigna y no te devuelve nada. Y como esta puedes hacerlo con el resto de tus variables.

Comment: sin embargo no puedo por medio de un Test (Class) no puedo llamarlo no me sale la funcion de entrar variables ``` Dominio Desaparecidos = new Dominio();  ; String Saludable = Dominio;```  @Enrique